# How to install python packages in python3.6 folder?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python, apt-get, python3

After extracting .tar.gz and running `python setup install`, selenium gets installed in,

```
....
creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium-3.4.3-py2.7.egg
Extracting selenium-3.4.3-py2.7.egg to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Adding selenium 3.4.3 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium-3.4.3-py2.7.egg
.....
```

where `python` is python 2.7 but not python3.6

---

On running,

```
$ python functionalTest.py
```

it works fine

But

```
$ python3.6 functionalTest.py
```

gives, error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
```

because I could not install selenium using python3.6 on Ubuntu, successfully, as shown below,

```
$ ls setup*
setup.cfg  setup.py
$ python3.6 setup install
python3.6: can't open file 'setup': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
$ python3.6 setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 22, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'
.....
Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 22, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'
$
```

After installing `setuptools`, below is the observation,

```
$ python3.6 setup.py install
.....
creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium-3.4.3-py2.7.egg
Extracting selenium-3.4.3-py2.7.egg to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
selenium 3.4.3 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium-3.4.3-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for selenium==3.4.3
Finished processing dependencies for selenium==3.4.3
$ cd /usr/local/lib/python
python2.7/ python3.5/ python3.6/ 
$ 
$ easy_install --version
setuptools 20.7.0 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (Python 2.7)
$ pip --version
pip 8.1.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
$
```

---

**Question:**

1)
Why selenium, easy_install & pip is installed in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`? I need these packages in `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages`.

2)
How to configure for python3.6 to pick selenium?

3)
Why `python --version` does not show *python 3.6* except asked explicitly `python3.6 --version`?

Comment: Enter `pip3 install selenium`

Comment: @n8te I already  tried, but same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Given the name of the package (selenium-3.4.3-***py2.7***.egg) this is a package for Python 2.7. Find the package for Python 3.6.
2. Install the adequate package for Python 3.6
3. Because by default `python` on most Linux distros is still 2.7 due to many scripts written for 2.7

On my Ubuntu 16.04 the `python3` package from the repos is Python 3.5.3 (`sudo apt install python3`). Selenium can also be installed from the repos (`sudo apt install python3-selenium`).

Comment: What about easy_install and pip?

Comment: The packages in your distro (`apt install`) are normally tested for compatibility with the rest of your system and will install dependencies if necessary.